# Texture in 3D model generated by SceneKit

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit, arkit, metalkit

I'm trying to create an app similar to PolyCam using Lidar . I'm using SceneKit mesh reconstruction and able to apply some random textures. But need real-world textures in generated output 3D Model. Found few examples available which are related to MetalKit and Point Cloud, which was not helpful.

Can you help me out with any references/steps/tutorial to how to achieve it .

Comment: Hi, I don't fully understand, what you are exactly trying to achieve, maybe you could add more details, and what you already did. If it comes to ARKit/SceneKit and Real-Time Texture from the Camera-Feed, this here could be probably helfpul: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73450837/scenekit-how-to-assign-arscnview-video-feed-as-a-texture-to-a-scngeometry/73471136#73471136

Comment: @ZAY I'm trying to generate 3D model from LiDar Data . SceneKit session data can be used to generate a 3D model but with No Texture from real-world .